# Select all active records and the first occurrence of inactive record without using union

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am currently trying to write a query that selects all active records and the first occurrence of inactive records from a table of products. I am currently using a union clause to achieve this. This is done by selecting all active records and unioning a dataset containing the active record per product with the earliest date. I am sure there is another way to write this that is more efficient. I have included some sample code below.

```
CREATE table #ActiveProduct
(
PRODUCT_ID INT NOT NULL,
Product_Month INT NOT NULL,
IsActive bit not null
)



INSERT into  #ActiveProduct
values (1,202001,1)
,(1,202001,1)
,(1,202002,1)
,(1,202003,1)
,(1,202004,1)
,(1,202005,0)
,(1,202006,0)
,(1,202007,0)
,(2,202001,1)
,(2,202002,1)
,(2,202003,1)
,(2,202004,1)
,(2,202005,1)
,(3,202002,1)
,(3,202003,0)
,(3,202005,0)

select * from  #ActiveProduct
```

My desired output on this data is:

[image]

Comment: You can do it with an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause, but it's likely to produce the same query plan.  If you want help with query performance, you will have to provide more specific detail.  Most helpful would the your current code and query plan.

Comment: Assuming you have an index on `IsActive` with `INCLUDE` columns then a `UNION ALL` query is likely to be faster than any other option, including the one posted by @lptr as you can see from this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=20eb43323eeae45903b167dde0c2db34